# I have a oriented bounding box calculated using MathGeoLib. I want to find the orientation of the bounding box in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics, computational-geometry, unity3d-editor

https://github.com/juj/MathGeoLib
http://clb.confined.space/MathGeoLib/nightly/docs/OBB_summary.php

I have calculated the bounding box for a set of points, I want to create a cube with the orientation of the bounding box. To create it with the orientation of the Object Aligned box, I need to find its orientation in x,y,z axis.

I tried using The Extents and Axis1,Axis2,Axis3, but they have different meanings.

```
rotation = 0;
var verts = vertices.Select(p => new Vector3((float)p.X, (float)p.Y, (float)p.Z)).ToArray();

OrientedBoundingBox obb = OrientedBoundingBox.OptimalEnclosing(verts);

            basePoint = new Vector2(obb.Center.x, obb.Center.z);

            Vector3[] corners =
        {
            obb.CornerPoint(0),
            obb.CornerPoint(1),
            obb.CornerPoint(2),
            obb.CornerPoint(3),
            obb.CornerPoint(4),
            obb.CornerPoint(5),
            obb.CornerPoint(6),
            obb.CornerPoint(7)
        };`
```

Comment: I think you can use the [`LocalToWorld`](http://clb.confined.space/MathGeoLib/nightly/docs/OBB_LocalToWorld.php)  matrix in order to convert the world space orientation (`Quaternion.identity`) to the rotated one .. how exactly did you try to use the axis though as I would understand they can be used to do the same